# imaplib , imap_tools return an error after a few minutes. (imaplib.abort: command: SELECT => IMAP4rev1 Server logging out)

Tags: python, imap, imaplib, yahoo-mail, imap-tools

I use this code to get unseen and new messages from my yahoo mail and find the messages with a specific URL.

```
from imap_tools import MailBox, AND
import re
from config import  email, password
from scrap import scrap

yahooSmtpServer = "imap.mail.yahoo.com"
client = MailBox(yahooSmtpServer).login(email, password, 'INBOX')
while True:
    msgs = client.fetch(AND(seen=False))
    for msg in msgs:
        mail = msg.html
        if 'pick' in mail and not 'Combo-pick' in mail:
            for i in re.findall(r'(https?://[^\s]+)', mail):
                if 'pick' in i:
                    link = i.replace('"', "")
                    print(link)
                    try:
                        scrap(link)
                    except:
                        pass
                    
        client.seen(msg.uid, True)
    client.logout()
    client = MailBox(yahooSmtpServer).login(email, password, 'INBOX')
```

most of the time it works for some time. around 15 minutes. then it returns an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\imaplib.py", line 1047, in _command_complete
    typ, data = self._get_tagged_response(tag, expect_bye=logout)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\imaplib.py", line 1165, in _get_tagged_response
    self._check_bye()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\imaplib.py", line 961, in _check_bye
    raise self.abort(bye[-1].decode(self._encoding, 'replace'))
imaplib.abort: IMAP4rev1 Server logging out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\yahooMail (2)\yahooMail (1)\main.py", line 24, in <module>
    client = MailBox(yahooSmtpServer).login(email, password, 'INBOX')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\imap_tools\mailbox.py", line 44, in login
    self.folder.set(initial_folder)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\imap_tools\folder.py", line 37, in set
    result = self.mailbox.box.select(encode_folder(folder))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\imaplib.py", line 756, in select
    typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, mailbox)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\imaplib.py", line 1230, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\imaplib.py", line 1049, in _command_complete
    raise self.abort('command: %s => %s' % (name, val))
imaplib.abort: command: SELECT => IMAP4rev1 Server logging out
```

Is there any way I can fix it? Or can I fetch the new/unseen Emails without login in every time? (When I tried to do it without login in a loop it didn't get the new messages).
Thank you.

Comment: Your code seems to try the mailbox as fast as it can, perhaps several times per second; why not add a `time.sleep(60)` 60 second delay so it polls at a more friendly rate?

Comment: @barny I know but I want to get the emails as soon as they'll arrive. I fixed it temporarily using a try except. But I wanna know what exactly this error is

Comment: “As soon as they arrive” - so use a 1 second sleep. Just try it, see if it helps?

Comment: @barny I will. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should consider IMAP IDLE protocol extension described in RFC2177

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2177

since 0.51.0 imap_tools has IDLE support:

https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools/releases/tag/v0.51.0

Comment: Thank you. I will try it as well. for now, I fixed it using some exceptions. it redefines the client every time it'll return the error. I picked that way cause imap_tools is way easier than working with imaplib